# Configure SQL Output

Tags: liquibase

The sql output produced by our Liquibase environment always contains the line `SET DEFINE OFF` as the first line of code. Now I need Liquibase to insert another `SET ...`.
Can someone point me some piece of documentation on how to do this?
thanks & cheers
Lugi

Answer (score 0):

Just use SQL tags in your changelog file like this:

```
<sql> SET... </sql>
```

wherever you want to insert this.

Comment: The problem is, that the DBAs want this in general. Therefore the risk of any developer forgetting about this is pretty high. And there are a few, devs come, devs leave (as did I in the meantime). So this is not an option. What I did, however, is a workaround: Since the files get parsed by gradle a job anyway after they have been generated (to find and replace potentially dangerous characters), I just insert the wanted line at the beginning of the file there. Hacky, but works for me.